# Matching inside square Brackets in Perl

Tags: perl

When I try to match 2 variables which are same, it works until there is a square bracket in perl for me.

For ex, VAR1 = u6701, VAR2 = u6701 matches and gives me EQUAL
However, VAR1 = aw[101], VAR2 = aw[101] gives me UNEQUAL.

I use $VAR1 == $VAR2 to check and both the variables are strings. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like Perl.  I suspect you're not showing us the real code.

Comment: Although just to confuse the issue a bit - scalars are actually dual value behind the scenes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186617/concerns-with-concatenating-strings-and-ints/28187890#28187890

Comment: @Sobrique Total digression, but I can't help myself. A scalar can be a triple value, [a PVNV can hold string, integer and double representations of a scalar](https://gist.github.com/schwern/d4dcf7523151acd9e0b8).  You can read all about it in [illguts - Illustrated Perl Guts](https://github.com/rurban/illguts/blob/master/illguts.pdf?raw=true).

Answer (score 3):

`==` is the numeric equality operator in Perl, it checks that two things are equal *as numbers*.  `eq` is the string equality operator, that's what you want to be using.  "1" and "01.00" are equal as numbers but not as strings.  [Here's the docs on all the equality operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).  There is also the pretty good online book [Beginning Perl](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/).

Why `==` sometimes works is because Perl is pretty liberal, to the point of desperation, about interpreting strings as numbers.  Often it will simply consider a string to be 0, but sometimes it will find a number in the string and use it.  For example, "101aw" will be interpreted as 101, but "aw101" is 0.  Do not rely on this.

BTW  Perl will warn you about all this, but not by default.  You have to [turn on strict and warnings](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088) and I *highly* recommend you do and deal with all the issues it brings up.  It will save you (and us) lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

In perl in order to check two string values I recommend you to use `eq`

for eg

```
if($VAR1 eq $VAR2)
       return true;
else
       return false;
```

`==` tests equality for numbers.
`eq` does the same for strings.

You can also use the `cmp` operator, which is the non-numerical equivalent of the <=> operator:

```
$result = $string1 cmp $string2;
```

$result will be:

```
`0` if the strings are equal
`1` if string1 is greater than string2
`-1` if string1 is less than string2
```